# Laravel 5.1 - Authenticate Username, Password AND if confirmed = 1

Tags: php, authentication, laravel-5, laravel-5.1, laravel-authorization

Pulling my hair out over what seems a simple task. I use the `username` instead of `email` in my `AuthController` using the following code:

```
/**
 * Set the login system to use username instead of email address
 * @var string
 */
protected $username = 'username';
```

This has worked fine for a long time (when I wasn't planning on users activating their accounts). However, now I need users to activate their accounts, I know I need to do additional checks on login before they can see their dashboard.

I have modified the `postLogin()` method below, to what I thought would be correct:

```
public function postLogin(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'username' => 'required', 'password' => 'required',
    ]);

    $credentials = $request->only('username', 'password');
    $credentials = array_add($credentials, 'confirmed', '1');

    if ($this->auth->attempt($credentials, $request->has('remember')))
    {
        return redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath());
    }

    return redirect($this->loginPath())
                ->withInput($request->only('username', 'remember'))
                ->withErrors([
                    'username' => $this->getFailedLoginMessage(),
                ]);
}
```

But all I get is the following error:

`Undefined property: App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController::$auth`

What is it that i'm doing wrong?

Andy

Comment: I don't think the problem starts in this piece of code. Can you post your AuthController ?

Comment: Without this piece of code it's fine

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just one glitch that I see there.

`if ($this->auth->attempt($credentials, $request->has('remember')))`

should be

`if (Auth::attempt($credentials, $request->has('remember')))`

Comment: Well that worked, how comes I need to change this though?

Comment: I just trust documentation and follow their code. I have no time and expertise to judge laravel's designers. :)

Comment: I meant and explanation as to why it needed to change, not to judge Laravel lol. Usually answers have an explanation as to why you need to do the changes

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel 5.1, the $auth attribute does not exist in the AuthController class constructor, as explained in the [5.1 upgrade guide](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/upgrade#upgrade-5.1.0). So you're referencing a property which does not exist.

Comment: Indeed, but this was a year ago and to be fair, was my first Laravel project (didn't upgrade from Laravel 5, went straight in at 5.1) so at the time the accepted answer is what helped. Thank you for the explanation though, hopefully someone will benefit from it :)